# WSO2 Identity Server UserAdmin SOAP interface

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'd like to know if it is possible to retrieve the user claims via the UserAdmin SOAP interface? I have found when adding a user it is possible to specify user claims. Also i have noticed that get list of user by Claims is possible but I have not found how to retrieve all the claims of a user.

Any hint?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try "RemoteUserStoreManagerService" for your purpose.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.ws.um.carbon.wso2.org">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:getUserClaimValues>
         <ser:userName>admin</ser:userName>
      </ser:getUserClaimValues>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Above request will return you the claims of admin user of its default profile.

---

**EDIT**

As per the comment you need the WSDL of new admin service.

By default WSDLs of admin services are hidden. To change that behavior open `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/carbon.xml` then locate `HideAdminServiceWSDLs` tag and set it to `false`.

Then you can view WSDL of any admin service from the url

```
https://localhost:9443/services/<SERVICE_NAME>?wsdl
```

In this case

```
https://localhost:9443/services/RemoteUserStoreManagerService?wsdl
```

HTH,

DarRay,

Comment: Do you have a WSDL for this? It is not part of UserAdmin WSDL? thanks

Comment: This is a separate admin service. I have updated the answer according to your comment